# JavaScript extending types return

Tags: javascript, extension-methods, prototypal-inheritance, function-prototypes

I'm actually studying  Crockford's *Javascript: the good parts*. I am new to JavaScript so I'm having a difficult time to understand how this code works:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

**Here's what I think:**

Being a method (a function inside an object), `this` points to the `Function` object, but why the need to return the object since i'm having access on it from inside the method? If i am right, `this` is a reference, not a local copy, so:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
};
```

Should work as well.

From the other side, in JavaScript a function without a return statement returns `undefined` and assign it to `Function.prototype.method`.

## The Question

**What's the point of returning `this`?**

---

### Working example #1

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
var add = function(a, b) {
    return a+b;
};

Function.method('add', add);
var f = function() {};

print(f.add(1,2));

Number.method('integer', function () {
        return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this);
        });

print((-10/3).integer());
```

**Output:**

> -3 
>   3

---

### Working Example #2

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
};

var add = function(a, b) {
    return a+b;
};

Function.method('add', add);
var f = function() {};

print(f.add(1,2));

Number.method('integer', function () {
        return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this);
        });

print((-10/3).integer());
```

**Output:**

> -3
>    3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let me try to explain it. I didn't read that book, but an article [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) of Douglas Crockford has one important sentence, related to that example about Function.prototype.method:

> It returns this. When I write a method
>   that doesn't need to return a value, I
>   usually have it return this. It allows
>   for a cascade-style of programming.

actually I am not familiar with that term, I think well known term is "[Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)" or "Method Chaining", read that wiki page, there are examples in different languages, so you will understand it..

PS. @Gianluca Bargelli was a bit faster to provide example of using Function.prototype.method this way, so I don't post it in my answer

**ADDON:** how you can use it in terms of your example:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
}

Number.method('integer', function () {  // you add 'integer' method
        return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this);
        })
      .method('square', function () {  // you add 'square' method with help of chaining
        return this * this;
        });

console.info( (-10/3).integer().square() ); // <- again chaining in action
```

you see, integer() returns Number object, so you can call another method, instead of writing:

```
var a = (-10/3).integer();
console.info( a.square() );
```

and few words about my way of using it, most of time I prefer to write "each method - new line with indent, for me this way is more readable:

```
Function.method('add', add)
        .method('sub', sub)
        .method('mul', mul)
        .method('div', div);
```

this way I see where I start, and "new line/indent" tell me that I still modify that object. Compare it to long line:

```
Function.method('add', add).method('sub', sub).method('mul', mul).method('div', div);
```

or typical approach:

```
Function.method('add', add);
Function.method('sub', sub);
Function.method('mul', mul);
Function.method('div', div);
```

**ADDON2:** Usually I use this approach (Fluent interface pattern) when I work with entities e.g. Java code:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  ..

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public Person setName( String newName ) {
    this.name = newName;
    return this;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
  }

  public Person setAge( int newAge ) {
    this.age = newAge;
    return this;
  }

  ..
}
```

it allows me to construct `Person` object in easy way:

```
Person person = new Person().setName("Leo").setAge(20);
```

Some people make it a bit different, they add new kind of methods to `set`/`get`, and call it `with` :

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  ..

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public void setName( String newName ) {
    this.name = newName;
  }

  public Person withName( String newName ) {
    this.setName( newName ); // or this.name = newName; up to you
    return this;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
  }

  public void setAge( int newAge ) {
    this.age = newAge;
  }

  public Person withAge( int newAge ) {
    this.setAge( newAge ); // or this.age = newAge; up to you
    return this;
  }
  ..
}
```

Now my previous example looks like:

```
Person person = new Person().withName("Leo").withAge(20);
```

This way we don't change meaning of set method (I mean we do not enhance it, so it work as most of developers expect... at least that people do not expect that `set` method can return anything ;) ). One interesting thing about these special methods - they can loose their self-documenting, but they improve readability when you use them (like in example with `Person` creation, `withName` tells very well what exactly we are doing..

to read more:
[FluentInterface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) - Martin Fowler's description of that pattern
[Fluent Interfaces in PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/1362)
[The Weekly Source Code 14 - Fluent Interface Edition](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode14FluentInterfaceEdition.aspx) - as for me short and good enough to see pros and cons (as well as links to other resources)

Comment: You're right. It's all about method chaining, see my answer above.

Comment: I've answered my own question, but if you can provide a better example than mine and some resources on the subject, i'll be happy to mark your answer.

Comment: @Gianluca Bargelli, sorry I didn't notice that replier and answerer was the same :) I added an example, if more needed just let me know

Comment: Thank you for the effort :) I also voted up your answer because it's very complete :)

Comment: @Gianluca Bargelli, did my best :) For JavaScript examples you can take a look at [jQuery API](http://jquery.com/), it follows this way very heavily

Answer (score 5):

I have sent an email to [Douglas Crockford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) this afternoon with this question and his reply was:

> F.method(a).method(b).method(c)

I'm not joking. This was the **only** thing he wrote.

Anyway, my personal intepretation of his (cryptic) answer is **Chain method creation**:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this; //This returns the same Function object into the chain below
};

var add = function (a, b) { return a+b; };
var sub = function (a, b) { return a-b; };
var mul = function (a, b) { return a*b; };
var div = function (a, b) { return a/b; };

Function.method('add', add).method('sub', sub).method('mul', mul).method('div', div);
```

That is, instead of creating new methods using **one** line at time, it is possible to **re-apply** the next method in the chain on the return object of the previous, `Function`.

In this example, the chain goes from *left to right*:

```
|Function|--method-->|add|--returns-->|Function|--method-->|sub|--returns-->|Function|--method-->|mul|--returns-->|Function|--method-->|div|-->returns-->|Function|
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you ask but if you don't return anything you will assign nothing to Function.prototype.method, witch kind of make that sentence useless don't you think?

Comment: I'll edit the question with a working example; the problem is that Function.prototype.method is not set to `undefined` as you'll see.

Comment: Try this: give a value to Function.prototype.method. Run the code you asked about. Check the next value... if it has changed... I can't answer your question :). If not... there's your answer.

Comment: You mean `Function.prototype.method = 2; `Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) { this.prototype[name] = name; };`? The last assignment overrides it.